# Notice: Undefined index: sort_data

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel

I have retrieved some data like this:

```
  array (size=2)
  'status' => string 'ok' (length=2)
  'data' => 
    array (size=5)
      'sort_data' => 
        array (size=2)
          'sort_column' => string 'order_item_id' (length=13)
          'sort_order' => string 'asc' (length=3)
```

Now I need to access `sort_column`, so I tried this:

```
$response = json_decode($response,true)
foreach($response['data'] as $data){
    echo $data["sort_data"]["sort_column"];
}
```

But I get these errors:

```
Notice: Undefined index: sort_data
Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null
```

So how to fix this issue?

### Update

Results of `dd($response['data'])`:

```
array (size=5)
  'sort_data' => 
    array (size=2)
      'sort_column' => string 'order_item_id' (length=13)
      'sort_order' => string 'asc' (length=3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$response['data']['sort_data']["sort_column"]
```

or

```
foreach($response['data']['sort_data'] as $key=>$value){
    echo $key."=".$value;
  
}
```

Comment: Warning: Illegal string offset 'sort_column'

Comment: try dd($response['data']) before loop and  post resultr

Comment: I just added an **UPDATE #1**,

Comment: updated my answer.try it if any error then let me know